# Sending SMIME E-Mail using Open SSL, the email body is not displaying

Tags: email, openssl, multipart, smime

When create s/mime email using OpenSSL, and send , the receiving email has smime content attached and signature is verified, but the email body is not visible through email clients such as Mac Mail and ThunderBird. All webmails (eg: Gmail) reads email body properly.

Has anybody ever experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

Would request to check the mail body for any parsing error. Most of web mailers have advanced mime parsing techniques which are usually based on real time data. But clients like outlook,mac have strictly followed the rfc standards for mail parsings.

I have seen mails which open properly in rediffmail but not on yahoo, also the mails which opens on web interfaces but on outlook they just crap out. Similarly for thunderbird also, but there few extensions available for thunderbird. If you install them then the mails starts to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

You must have used NO_DETACHED signing an MIME. Just like this:

```
int flags = PKCS7_STREAM;
p7 = PKCS7_sign(scert, skey, NULL, in, flags);
```

NO_DETACHED means that OpenSSL would sign and pack all of the MIME and the signedData to a .p7m file, which means a normal client could only find a .p7m file in the email. Just use DETACHED flag by which OpenSSL would add a .p7s file as signature data in the end of the previous MIME struct instead of packing all of them.

First:

```
flags |= PKCS7_DETACHED;
```

And sign it.

```
p7 = PKCS7_sign(scert, skey, NULL, in, flags);
```

Example:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/demos/smime/smsign.c